# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrational, and $r\neq 0$ is rational, could $\alpha+\beta$ be rational? $\sqrt{\alpha}$? $\sqrt{r}$? $\alpha\beta$? etc

Tags: real-analysis

Little background, $\alpha$, $\beta$ are irrational, $r$ is the non-zero rational number. We are asked to tick the boxes where the result may end up being rational. The following has been declined as the correct answer for me.

[image]

I am fairly certain that my marked boxes are correct, which means I am missing one of the unticked options. I think it may be $\sqrt{\alpha + \sqrt{\beta}}$, though I cannot come up with an example...

Comment: Suppose $\beta = \pi$ and $\alpha = -\sqrt {\pi}$  (nothing special about $\pi$...pick your favorite positive irrational).

Comment: yup... that works. thanks

Comment: It doesn't have to be zero either, $\sqrt{(r^2 - \sqrt{\pi}) +\sqrt{\pi}} = |r| $ can be any positive rational

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for the addition you can choose two numbers of opposite signs, for $\sqrt{r}$ you can choose $r = k ^ 2$, for multiplication you can choose $\sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2}$ and for the last one , the example with $\pi$ and $-\sqrt{\pi}$ works.

Comment: Try using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)